# How to use grep and awk together to get specific part of a url/string

Tags: jenkins, groovy, svn, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

So I have a svn repo URL like this--

```
svn info
Path: .
URL: svn://xyz-repo/svn/ccsmp/branches/features/cre40_jenkins
Repository Root: svn://xyz-repo/svn/ccsmp
Repository UUID: 5de8f2f4-0d3b-0410-8f2c-d418a2640d16
Revision: 23430
```

I want to grab only this part--

```
branches/features/cre40_jenkins
```

So far I have tried something like this

```
def BRANCH_NAME = sh(script: " svn info | grep -Po 'Relative URL: \\^/\\K.*' ", returnStdout: true , trim: true)
```

But this didn't worked as I am using a very old Jenkins version with old plugins and svn.

Is there any other way to do this. Please help any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def BRANCH_NAME = sh(script:""" cat svn info | grep URL | cut -d "-" -f2 | cut -d "/" -f 4-6 """, returnStdout: true , trim: true)
```

output : branches/features/cre40_jenkins

Comment: I tried this but I got the following error-org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: unclassified method java.lang.String div java.lang.String

Comment: I approved all the pending In-process Script Approvals but still I keep getting this.

Comment: And also thank you soooooo much for taking the time to answer my questions I highly highly appreciate you helping me

Comment: @sankraken, sounds like you're not using triple quoted string.

Comment: @sandeepp Thank you soooooooooooo much for your help you saved me

Comment: @daggett Thank you soo much I had no idea that I was suppose to use triple quoted string.